# android internet permission not working

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

I'm trying to set-up facebook connect with my program. I had it working before, but I've switched to a new computer and now for some reason permission isn't being granted. Whenever I hit my facebok connect button, an error pops up, "Application requires permission to access the internet". My manifest file is below. Anyone see anything wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myname.appname" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="false"
    android:anyDensity="false" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".LoginPage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/login_tag">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
    </uses-permission>
    <activity android:name=".mainDisplay" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: you switched the pc? So you are running this on the emulator? Does it work on a device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<uses-permission>` element needs to be outside of the `<application>` element.

Answer (score 2):

While adding permission ,it must add like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Jouzer_Android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    />

</manifest>
```

Comment: This is a better answer than your previous three; Please keep posting more like this, and don't do any more of the "here's a link" type of answers. :)

Comment: Make sure it looks exactly, i mean just the actual permission(Internet) has to be in uppercase